# Sum of squares of each interval

Tags: python, python-3.x, interval

> ***Q.*** Write three similar functions, each of which takes as an argument a sequence of intervals and returns the sum of the square of each interval that does not contain 0.
>
> - Using a for statement containing an if statement.
> - Using map and filter and reduce.
> - Using generator expression and reduce.
>
> Hint: Square is a special case of quadratic, but you can also use the simpler square_interval function below for intervals that do not contain 0:

```
def non_zero(x):
    """Return whether x contains 0."""
    return lower_bound(x) > 0 or upper_bound(x) < 0

def square_interval(x):
    """Return the interval that contains all squares of values in x, where x
    does not contain 0.
    """
    assert non_zero(x), 'square_interval is incorrect for x containing 0'
    return mul_interval(x, x)

# The first two of these intervals contain 0, but the third does not.
seq = (interval(-1, 2), make_center_width(-1, 2), make_center_percent(-1, 50))

zero = interval(0, 0)

def sum_nonzero_with_for(seq):
    """Returns an interval that is the sum of the squares of the non-zero
    intervals in seq, using a for statement.

    >>> str_interval(sum_nonzero_with_for(seq))
    '0.25 to 2.25'
    """
    "*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"

from functools import reduce
def sum_nonzero_with_map_filter_reduce(seq):
    """Returns an interval that is the sum of the squares of the non-zero
    intervals in seq, using using map, filter, and reduce.

    >>> str_interval(sum_nonzero_with_map_filter_reduce(seq))
    '0.25 to 2.25'
    """
    "*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"

def sum_nonzero_with_generator_reduce(seq):
    """Returns an interval that is the sum of the squares of the non-zero
    intervals in seq, using using reduce and a generator expression.

    >>> str_interval(sum_nonzero_with_generator_reduce(seq))
    '0.25 to 2.25'
    """
    "*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"
```

Below is the solution:

```
# Representation 1
def make_center_width(c, w):
    """Construct an interval from center and width."""
    return interval(c - w, c + w)

def center(x):
    """Return the center of interval x."""
    return (upper_bound(x) + lower_bound(x)) / 2


def width(x):
    """Return the width of interval x."""
    return (upper_bound(x) - lower_bound(x)) / 2

#Representation 2
def make_center_percent(c, p):
    """ Construct an interval from center and tolerance.

    >>> str_interval(make_center_percent(2, 50))
    '1.0 to 3.0'
    """
    w = c * (p/100)
    return interval(c - w, c + w)

def percent(x):
   """Retunr the percentage tolerance of interval x.

   >>> percent(interval(1, 3))
   50.0
   """
   w  = ((upper_bound(x) - lower_bound(x))/2)
   c  = ((upper_bound(x) + lower_bound(x))/2)
   return (w/c)*100.0

#Representation 3
def interval(a, b):
    """Construct an interval from a to b. """
    return (a, b)

def lower_bound(x):
    """Return the lower bound of interval x. """
    return x[0]

def upper_bound(x):
    """Return the upper bound of interval x. """
    return x[1]
# Representation 3 - end

#Usage - starts
def str_interval(x):
    """Return a string representation of interval x.
    >>> str_interval(interval(-1, 2))
    '-1 to 2'
    """
    return '{0} to {1}'.format(lower_bound(x), upper_bound(x))

def mul_interval(x, y):
    """Return the interval that contains the product of any value in x and any
    value in y.

    >>> str_interval(mul_interval(interval(-1, 2), interval(4, 8)))
    '-8 to 16'
    """
    p1 = lower_bound(x) * lower_bound(y)
    p2 = lower_bound(x) * upper_bound(y)
    p3 = upper_bound(x) * lower_bound(y)
    p4 = upper_bound(x) * upper_bound(y)
    return interval(min(p1, p2, p3, p4), max(p1, p2, p3, p4))

def add_interval(x, y):
    """Return an interval that contains the sum of any value in interval x and
    any value in interval y.
    >>> str_interval(add_interval(interval(-1, 2), interval(4, 8)))
    '3 to 10'
    """
    lower = lower_bound(x) + lower_bound(y)
    upper = upper_bound(x) + upper_bound(y)
    return interval(lower, upper)

def non_zero(x):
    """Return whether x contains 0."""
    return lower_bound(x) > 0 or upper_bound(x) < 0

def square_interval(x):
    """Return the interval that contains all squares of values in x, where x
    does not contain 0.
    """
    assert non_zero(x), 'square_interval is incorrect for x containing 0'
    return mul_interval(x, x)

# The first two of these intervals contain 0, but the third does not.
seq = (interval(-1, 2), make_center_width(-1, 2), make_center_percent(-1, 50))

zero = interval(0, 0)

def sum_nonzero_with_for(seq):
    """Returns an interval that is the sum of the squares of the non-zero
    intervals in seq, using a for statement.

    >>> str_interval(sum_nonzero_with_for(seq))
    '0.25 to 2.25'
    """
    result = zero
    for interval in seq:
        if  non_zero(interval):
            result = add_interval(result, square_interval(interval))
    if non_zero(result):
        return result

from functools import reduce
def sum_nonzero_with_map_filter_reduce(seq):
    """Returns an interval that is the sum of the squares of the non-zero
    intervals in seq, using using map, filter, and reduce.

    >>> str_interval(sum_nonzero_with_map_filter_reduce(seq))
    '0.25 to 2.25'
    """
    return reduce(add_interval, map(square_interval, filter(non_zero, seq)))

def sum_nonzero_with_generator_reduce(seq):
    """Returns an interval that is the sum of the squares of the non-zero
    intervals in seq, using using reduce and a generator expression.

    >>> str_interval(sum_nonzero_with_generator_reduce(seq))
    '0.25 to 2.25'
    """
    return reduce(add_interval, (square_interval(interval) for interval in seq if non_zero(interval)))
```

Can we improve this solution?

Comment: *"improvise"* -> *"improve"*? And, if so, do you have some criteria for what constitutes better?

Comment: DO I need to check extra condition here `if non_zero(result)`. I mean removing unnecessary code apart from 3 representations.

Answer (score 1):

A few general comments first:

- Use more descriptive variable names. It’s harder to discern the meaning of single-letter variables. Better names will make it easier to read and follow your code.

  Here’s a simple example:

  ```
  def make_center_width(center, width):
      """Construct an interval from center and width."""
      return interval(center - width, center + width)
  ```

  It’s almost exactly the same, but using the full words make it easier to follow than using `c` and `w`.

  If the variable is an interval, I suggest the variable name `intvl`. You probably don't want to use the name `interval`, to avoid clashing with the function, and `int` clashes as well.
- Use spaces around binary operators. In particular, you need some more spaces in the final line of `percent()`. ([PEP 8: *Other recommendations*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations))
- In your docstrings, I wouldn’t apply `str_interval` in your examples. The output is just a tuple, e.g.:

  ```
  >>> add_interval(interval(-1, 2), interval(4, 8))
  (3, 10)
  ```

  The output is just as easy to read, but the example is slightly cleaner.
- Lines should always be 79 characters or less; the final line of `sum_nonzero_with_generator_reduce()` breaks this rule. ([PEP 8: *Maximum Line Length*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id14))
- In the docstring of `make_center_percent()`, you should remove the first space in the docstring. In the docstring of `percent()`, the word "Return" is misspelt.

It’s not clear which code comes from the assignment, and which is stuff you’ve added independently. I think (if I’ve interpreted correctly) that these are design decisions made in the teacher’s code, but worth mentioning anyway:

- You have a module import (functools) near the bottom of your code. Module imports should always be at the top of the file; see [PEP 8: *Imports*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports).
- Rather than making an interval a tuple, I'd consider creating an `Interval` class, making `upper` and `lower` class properties, and making your functions class methods. I’m not sure if it’s better, but it’s my gut instinct.

And now some comments on your specific functions:

- In `make_center_percent()`, you calculate the width and are given the center, so why not use `make_center_width()` to create the returned interval?
- In `interval()`, you do nothing to check that the interval makes sense. What if I enter strings, or have a > b, or drop in some nested tuples? You should do some basic checking of the numbers entered here.
- Your `str_interval()` function doesn’t cover the case in which the interval is a singleton: e.g. `str_interval(interval(0, 0))` returns `0 to 0`. It should really return just `0`.
- In `mul_interval()`, rather than those four lines of multiplications, which are hard to read, you could instead use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). Given two tuples, it can compute their Cartesian product as an iterator.

  For example:

  ```
  from itertools import product

  x = (1, 3)
  y = (2, 4)
  print min(product(x, y)) # (1, 2)
  print max(product(x, y)) # (3, 4)
  ```

  There’s nothing particularly wrong with your approach; this is just an alternative.
- The docstring for `non_zero()` is quite confusing, and it took several attempts to wrap my head around it. In fact, the function tells me if the interval does *not* contain 0.

  I would create a new function `contains_zero()`, which tells me whether the function contains `0`, then replace all the calls to `non_zero()` by `not contains_zero()` instead. Much easier to follow.

  Or, if you take the class approach, then you can define the [`__contains__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) in your class and use `0 in x`. For example:

  ```
  >>> x = Interval(-1, 5)
  >>> 0 in x
  True
  >>> 6 in x
  False
  ```
- Your `sum_nonzero_with_for()` relies on the definition of a `zero` variable outside the function. That’s a bit fragile: it would be better if the `zero` interval is defined within the function.

  I’m also not sure why you have an if non-zero statement at the end of the function; mathematically, it should be impossible for an interval to contain zero at the end of this function. I’d put an `assert` here rather than an `if` statement. You want to spot the impossible behaviour immediately, not return `None` and wait for that to cause a problem elsewhere.
- In both `_with_map_filter_reduce()` and `_with_generator_reduce()`, you cram some quite complicated expressions into a single line. To make it easier to read, I’d suggest breaking these into several lines with intermediary variables.